# Is there any C# API available to query Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, api

Well, I am new in this arena. I want to know about any C# API available to query Stack Overflow to get the information like `Questions`, `Answers`, `Reputation`, `Votes`, `Tags` across different `Users`, etc.

There is one application available for mobile with the name `Stack Remote`, but that is still offering limited features.

I would appreciate if you can let me know about any application already built to provide such customized information or any valuable directions in this regard?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackapps.com yet?

Comment: Yes but there are so many applications there and i tried to search the most related application but no success. Couldn't find the appropriate application w.r.t my requirement. Can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `library` tag on Stack Apps to find wrappers around the API in various languages.  [StacMan - .NET client for Stack Exchange API v2](https://stackapps.com/q/3411/9) seems to be the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, Can i use Linq operations with it?